# Why doesn't capture graph in Directshow work?

Tags: c++, directshow, media, video-capture, directshow.net

[image: graph]

This is my graph. I capture media from Pinnacle Capture Card into MPEG-2 Encoder, but the output of this graph (test.mpeg) is wrong. The video and audio in this file doesn't match. The video will play faster than audio.

How to capture video from source into several format? (In example, I can see only AVI and ASF)

Answer (score 1):

To localize the problem try to remove encoder, insert AVI Mux filter, direct audio and video to it and connect its output to a file writer. If the video and audio will still be not synchronized, then the reason is in your video capture source. It is simply doesn't work properly.

Comment: I already try this solution, the output is AVI file format, but if I wanna capture the video to MPEG file format or the other codec. How should I do?

Comment: Let's first deal with audio/video sync. Did this AVI file have synchronized audio and video? As for other formats, I would suggest to use the graph only to capture video and audio samples and for compression use something like Windows Media Format SDK. You'll get a WMV file.